# Error in scaffold model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Previously I had created a model that worked quite well, but now stopped working possibly by some scaffold generated, my model is called `Motivonoventa` and pluralized is `Motivosnoventa`.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'motivonoventa', 'motivosnoventa'
```

I put `Motivonoventa.last` in the rails terminal but I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Invalid object name 'motivonoventa'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [motivonoventa].* FROM [motivonoventa]  ORDER BY [motivonoventa].[IdMot] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY'
from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:352:in `each'
```

this is my model:

```
class Motivonoventa < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "IdMot"
end
```

**inflections.rb**

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'motivonoventa', 'motivosnoventa'
  inflect.irregular 'vent', 'venta'
  inflect.irregular 'no_venta', 'noventas'
end
```

Comment: Can you just open the `rails console` again and type `"motivonoventa".pluralize` ? And check, `Motivonoventa.table_name` ?

Comment: @dp7 thanks for answer. yes, I got this:     => "motivonoventa"

Comment: @dp7 Should be pluralized to "motivosnoventa" but  I got this: => "motivonoventa"

Comment: Make sure you have done the changes to `/config/initializers/inflections.rb` and saved it properly!  Can you add the `inflections.rb` entire content to question ?

Comment: @dp7 sure, Is properly saved, I just added the inflections file

Comment: @dp7 I found the problem. Is inflicting with this:  inflect.irregular 'vent', 'venta'

Comment: @dp7 I do not know how he is inflicting with vent if he is motivonoventa is a word stuck